# Workaround of aplying a method to an object so method can acces "this" keyword as the object

Tags: javascript, function, methods

Sorry but I don't know how to ask this question... I'm going to explain it.

I have this code:

```
function jclass_getVar() {
    return this.myvar;
}
function jclass() {
    this.myvar = "ok";
    this.funcAry = [];
}
jclass.prototype.getVar = jclass_getVar;

var obj = new jclass();
```

Right now everything is fine. If I acces `obj.getVar()` it will return `ok`, but lets say I want to create an array of functions dinamically. This is my code:

```
function myMethod1() {
    return this.myvar;
}
function myMethod2() {
    return this.myvar;
}
obj.funcAry.push(myMethod1);
obj.funcAry.push(myMethod2);
```

And when I want to call the functions, I do this:

```
for (var i in obj.funcAry) {
    obj.tempmethod = obj.funcAry[i];
    obj.tempmethod();
}
obj.tempmethod = undefined;
```

I don't like to create a temporal variable to call the methods... Is there any "good" way of calling a method and the method "this" be the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, searching while questioning I've found the reply. The answer is the `apply` method:

Instead of:

```
obj.tempmethod = myMethod1;
obj.tempmethod();
obj.tempmethod = undefined;
```

I have to:

```
myMethod1.apply(obj);
```